# What kind of lifetime parameter do I have to use here when declaring a struct field object type

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

This is what my code looks like. I'm trying to use a impled struct within my `ShapeRenderer` struct and use its methods.

**shapes.rs:**

```
use super::core::*;

pub struct ShapeRenderer<'a> {
    core_renderer: &'a mut CanvasRenderer,
}
```

**core.rs**

```
pub struct Canvas {
    pub width: usize,
    pub height: usize,
    pub array: Vec<char>,
}

pub struct Point {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
}

pub struct CanvasRenderer<'a> {
    canvas: &'a mut Canvas,
}

impl<'a> CanvasRenderer<'a> {
    pub fn new(canvas: &'a mut Canvas) -> CanvasRenderer {
        CanvasRenderer { canvas: canvas }
    }
}
```

***Error***

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/shapes.rs:5:28
  |
5 |     core_renderer: &'a mut CanvasRenderer
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 lifetime parameter
```

I marked it with a lifetime parameter - why does it want another one? tried the object type with `<'a>` and appended it `<'a>` - neither of those attempts solved the problem.

Comment: Your design looks like you expect to hold two mut references to the same canvas. That's not going to work anyway.

Comment: ah wow! good points - thanks you point that out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CanvasRenderer` is parameterized over a lifetime, so you need to state what that lifetime is:

```
pub struct ShapeRenderer<'a> {
    core_renderer: &'a mut CanvasRenderer<'a>,
    //                                   ^^^^
}
```

However, this structure doesn't seem to have much purpose, it only adds indirection. Why have a reference to a thing that only has a reference? Skip the middleman:

```
pub struct ShapeRenderer<'a> {
    core_renderer: CanvasRenderer<'a>,
}
```

Comment: yea you're right I should directly start to instanciate CanvasRenderer in the ShapeRenderer ctor instead of giving it in as a reference. I think as I came to the implementation I maybe realized that. But doing test first - so wasnt that far yet ;) thanks for you help as always!